# Android Achartengine: Having multiple coloured points on a line graph of a different colour?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using Android AchartEngine to create my graph.

As of now, I'm able to render a time series graph, but Achartengine forces the line graphs to have consistent colour. What I want is a separate colour for the lines joining the data points, while the data points can be of any colour that I assign to.

How do I do this? if I use different datasets/renders, then they will all render different coloured lines.

I want something similar to a scatter graph overlapping on a line graph.

Comment: What do you want different colored lines or only different colored points?

Answer (score 1):

You can build an XY combined chart with one line chart and one scatter chart. Each would have a separate dataset and renderer, but the points would be similar.

An example for such a chart is available [here](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/CombinedTemperatureChart.java).

Comment: XYCombinedChartDef doesn't exist anymore. How do I go about making this work?

Comment: It does exist in version 1.2.0. You can get it here: https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/